# How to override this WordPress plugin template file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

So in plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search/templates/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search.php, there is a line I want to change in the label, from "Search for:" to "Search". If I change it in this file, it's fine, but of course I want to keep the change in my own theme rather than modify it here.

So, I copied the entire plugin folder over into my theme folder and made the change, but it's not working. The path is themes/MYTHEME/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search/templates/yith-woocommerce-ajax-search.php

Any clues why this isn't working?

Comment: If it's wrapped with a class or id or something, I probably would just use javascript/jQuery to replace the text on load. I don't know that it's worth the fuss to duplicate the plugin just for one small phrase.

Comment: After copying the entire plugin folder into your theme folder, did you include the root file of the plugin in your theme?

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian I'm not sure how to do this, so the answer is most likely no.

Comment: Alright. We just add a line in your functions.php file to include / require the plugin content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin uses `wc_get_template()` to load `yith-woocommerce-ajax-search.php`. This means that you can put the template file directly in the `themes/YOURTHEME/woocommerce/` directory, then your template should be loaded correctly.

Comment: Hey, you're right. It worked! May you please let me know where you saw the wc_get_template() method?

Comment: It is in `class.yith-wcas.php` starting at line 101.

Comment: Not sure how this works, but do you ask people here to accept an answer as the solution? :)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at this function earlier! I thought maybe I could have overridden this in my functions.php and redirected it to another template, instead. Great answer, I will accept it. Thank you.